# Boolean is transformed to Date R

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

I have a big excel file (xls) with different columns. Columns that contain "Yes" or "No" are transferred to 1899-12-31 or 1900-01-01 when read in with "read_xls".
In the excel file when I click on the columns they are either 0 or 1 but displayed as "Yes" or "No".
My goal is to have them say in R also "Yes" or "No" or "TRUE" "FALSE".

Has anyone a suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You can define the column type for each column with the `col_type` argument of `read_xls`. Using this you can also prevent `read_xls` from guessing the types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any other way to solve this? This would imply in my case to specify around 100 columns...

Comment: Are all "Yes" /"No" values transformed into "1899-12-30" and "1900-01-01"?

Comment: Yes, in every column that would display a "Yes"/"No" in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your data.frame is named `df` and your column containing the should-be-boolean variable is named `bool_var`. You could try this:

```
lookup <- c("1900-01-01" = "Yes", "1899-12-30" = "No")

df$bool_var <- lookup[as.character(df$bool_var)]
```

As an example, this transformation

```r
df$bool_var <- lookup[as.character(df$var)]
```

returns

```r
          var bool_var
1  1899-12-30       No
2  1899-12-30       No
3  1899-12-30       No
4  1899-12-30       No
5  1900-01-01      Yes
6  1900-01-01      Yes
7  1900-01-01      Yes
8  1900-01-01      Yes
9  1899-12-30       No
10 1900-01-01      Yes
```

If there are more than one column that need to be transformed and you know them by their column name, you could use

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(var), ~lookup[as.character(.x)]))
```

Replace `c(var)` with `c(col_name1, col_name2, col_name3, ...)`.